# is it grammatically correct to put a verb before a noun?

Tags: verbs

In the dictionary, *position* as a verb means "to determine the position of or locate".

1. What word would represent the adjectival form of *position*?  and what would its meaning be?
2. Is it acceptable grammatically for a verb to be put before a noun - eg a **positioning** device - to describing a device used to determine the position or location of something (eg It is a positioning device that locates optimal treatment sites).   If this is proper grammatically can you please elaborate on which grammatical rules are at work here that allow this?

Comment: This is not a verb being put before a noun. This is a modifier being put before a noun. "Do you use a green device? Do you use a GPS device? Do you use a positioning device?" Nothing to see here, move along. The grammatical rules at work here are that you can put a modifier before a noun. Can you please elaborate where *else* you would put the modifier in your sentence? (And if you can't, then there you have it, you agree that the question is really a non-starter.)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with using either *positioning* or *positioned* as adjectival forms of the verb *position*. These two forms are the present active participle and present passive participle respectively.

Using the present active participle of a verb as an adjective means something which is used in accomplishing the meaning of the verb. e.g., a positioning beacon = a beacon used to position other things.

Using the present passive participle of a verb as an adjective identifies something which has undergone the verb's activity, e.g. a positioned military unit = a military united that has been placed into position.

Thus, the adjectival forms of the verb *position* are  **positioning** and **positioned** depending on whether you want to speak of something that helps in positioning or is already positioned.

Answer (score 0):

Although in this particular context, I would prefer 'location device,' 'positioning device' is also perfectly acceptable.

When we expand the acronym 'GPS,' we get 'Global *Positioning* System,' which is exactly the same concept.

Almost any time we have a verb which ends with '-ing,' we can almost always use it as either a noun or an adjective without changing form. Take *walking,* for example:

As a verb, we say

```
 John is walking.
```

As a noun,

```
 John's walking improves his overall health.
```

And as an adjective,

```
 John just bought a new walking stick to use on nature hikes.
```

So yes, this is perfectly acceptable and correct.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it is grammatically correct to put a verb before a noun. Examples:

- Visualize a horse.
- Find yourself.
- Bring the food.
- Question everything.

In each of these examples, a noun subject ("you") is understood in a declarative sentence.

Here are some examples where something other than a noun is put before a verb which is positioned before a noun.

- Skiing creates relaxation.
- To sink and to swim are the facts of life.

Comment: Please elaborate a bit on your answer, the formatting is confusing and you don't go into detail on explaining your point. As an aside I find "Visualize horse." and "Bring bottle" to be odd phrases, with the articles omitted.

Answer (score -2):

verb + noun; Read the book. Print books. Find dreams. Use shadow, light the silence, bring yourself here. Think the headstone. Write the will.